Confused about usage of という
I came across this sentence:

地面が土で、周囲が木というだけで、暑さが随分とマシになった。
The heat became quite bearable when surrounded with trees and dirt.

I'm confused about what という is doing here?

Does this answer your question? The という in things like 〜ということ・〜というの・〜という感じ・〜というわけ etc

I'd interpret it as 周囲が木という環境だけで, where 環境 is omitted

Agreed, I think 状態 could also be subbed. I would also be careful to not confuse this というだけで with the one marking a reason
